# Recommended unittest framework / testrunner for Spotify Apps?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, frameworks, spotify

What would you recommend as unittest framework and / or testrunner when developing a Spotify Application..? It's pure javascript, and it's running inside the Spotify client, like this:

http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/overview/

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using [mocha.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) and [expect.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js) to run my unit tests inside Spotify.

Feel free to fork my base setup for a spotify app project. More information on how to write tests should be available in each of the libraries specified above.

https://github.com/Skoog/Spotify-Unittest